# Can I test PayPal IPN without actually making a purchase?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Can I test the PayPal IPN without actually making a purchase?

Is there a developer sandbox for testing the Request/Response functionality prior to actual implementation?

Basically, I have my server and would like to use the IPN feature to track my customer purchases and respond to a customer's purchase immediately.  I would first like to test this out with dummy payments to ensure that the PayPal IPN and my server are communicating correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check paypal's site... the link is: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside.

Sign up for a dev account, and inside there you can create test users and specify their paypal balances, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has a developer sandbox here https://developer.paypal.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get complete instructions:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/